# How do I display the Month, Month + 1, Month +2, Month +3, Month +4 in a separate column depending on the date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So this is my query so far:

```
declare @snaps table (hotel_id int, snapdate date, month int, year 
int) 
insert into @snaps
select hotel_id, max(import_date) as maximport_date, 
month(max(import_date)), year(max(import_Date))  
from ukrmc.dbo.block_Res 
where import_date between '2017-12-01' and '2018-12-31'  
group by month(import_date), year(import_Date), hotel_id--, market_seg 
--order by hotel_id, maximport_Date 

select     otb1.hotel_id
          ,otb1.snapdate
          ,otb1.month
          ,otb1.year 
from
       (select * from @snaps) otb1
```

Here is a sample of what this query gives me for one hotel_id :

```
hotel_id  snapdate    month  year
3         2017-12-31  12     2017
3         2018-01-31  1      2018
3         2018-02-28  2      2018
3         2018-03-30  3      2018
3         2018-04-30  4      2018
3         2018-05-31  5      2018
3         2018-06-30  6      2018
3         2018-07-31  7      2018
3         2018-08-31  8      2018
3         2018-09-30  9      2018
3         2018-10-06  10     2018
```

...and so on for each of the 50 hotel_id's.

I now want a column which displays the snapdate's month+year and each of the next 4 months. For example, for hotel_id 3 and the snapdates '2017-12-31' and '2018-01-31 (as an example) it should look like this:

```
hotel_id  snapdate    month  year    Month_TY
3         2017-12-31  12     2017    December 2017
3         2017-12-31  12     2017    January 2018
3         2017-12-31  12     2017    February 2018
3         2017-12-31  12     2017    March 2018
3         2017-12-31  12     2017    April 2018 
3         2018-01-31  1      2018    January 2018
3         2018-01-31  1      2018    February 2018
3         2018-01-31  1      2018    March 2018
3         2018-01-31  1      2018    April 2018
3         2018-01-31  1      2018    May 2018
```

I have no idea how I would even do something like this? Would I need to do something in select clause?

Comment: Inner join the results with `SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 ... UNION SELECT 4` and use the 5 numbers to generate the months.

Comment: @SalmanA Sorry, i do not understand. What would I do the inner join on?

Comment: in your example your input contains two rows `3, 2017-12-31` and `3, 2018-01-31` and you want 2x5 = 10 rows as output. The obvious solution is JOIN. You basically join on _any_ table that has 5 rows. `SELECT ... UNION` is one trick. `VALUES (0), (1), ..., (4)` is another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CROSS APPLY to calculate the 5 dates in your final SELECT statement and calculate the month-year-strings using DATENAME:

```
SELECT hotel_id, snapdate, month, year,
  DATENAME(MM, snapdateex) + N' ' + DATENAME(YYYY, snapdateex) AS Month_TY
FROM @snaps
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (snapdate),
    (DATEADD(month, 1, snapdate)),
    (DATEADD(month, 2, snapdate)),
    (DATEADD(month, 3, snapdate)),
    (DATEADD(month, 4, snapdate))) AS hlp(snapdateex)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is union, together with dateadd:

```
select otb1.hotel_id ,otb1.snapdate ,MONTH(otb1.snapdate) ,YEAR(otb1.snapdate) from (select * from @snaps) otb1

UNION ALL

select otb1.hotel_id ,otb1.snapdate ,MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1 , otb1.snapdate)) ,YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 1 , otb1.snapdate)) from (select * from @snaps) otb1

UNION ALL 

select otb1.hotel_id ,otb1.snapdate ,MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 2 , otb1.snapdate)) ,YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 2, otb1.snapdate)) from (select * from @snaps) otb1

UNION ALL 

select otb1.hotel_id ,otb1.snapdate ,MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 3 , otb1.snapdate)) ,YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 3, otb1.snapdate)) from (select * from @snaps) otb1
```